# The php file is returning false instead of the bind values.How can I fix this?

Tags: java, php, android, json, database

I have an android studio project connected to a mysql online database, using php files. 
The problem is I don't receive the parameters(idquestion, question, id) from the php file with a given idquestion and a category. 
The class and the php file are a similar replica to ohers that works and yet is not working.

I tried the debugger and i find out that i pass the correct information (idquestion 1 and category "computers").
Also, i tried another php file with a different syntax just to print data and it worked, but that php file wasn't helpful in my class.

This is my php file

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id8963226_user", "parola123", "id8963226_user");

    $idquestion = @($_POST['idquestion']);
    $category = @($_POST['category']);

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "select * from question where idquestion=? and category=?;");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "is", $idquestion, $question);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $success, $idquestion, $question, $id);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["idquestion"] = $idquestion;
        $response["question"] = $question;
        $response["id"] = $id;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

These are my java classes

```
package com.example.allrateform;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Question extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        //CREATING ALL INSTANCES FROM TEXTS
        final TextView CategoryTextView = findViewById(R.id.CategoryTextView);
        final TextView QuestionTextView = findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        final TextView IdTextView = findViewById(R.id.IdTextView);

        CategoryTextView.setText(Categories.Category);

        final String category = CategoryTextView.getText().toString();
        final int idquestion = 1;

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if (success) {

                        String question = jsonResponse.getString("question");
                        int id = jsonResponse.getInt("id");
                        QuestionTextView.setText(question);
                        IdTextView.setText(id);

                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Question.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Failed")
                                .setNegativeButton("Ok", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        };

        //CREATING RESPONSE
        ListRequest listRequest = new ListRequest(idquestion, category, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Question.this);
        queue.add(listRequest);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.allrateform;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ListRequest extends StringRequest {


    private static final String LIST_REQUEST_URL = "myUrl.com/myPhp.php";

    private Map<String, String> params;

    //METHOD TO PASS THE INFORMATION
    public ListRequest(int idquestion, String category, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LIST_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("idquestion", idquestion + "");
        params.put("category", category);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

So again the project result is "Failed", meaning the php returns false.

If you have other ways to approach this it's ok as long as I'm able to store all the question from the "computer" categories in a java string array.

Feel free to ask any other questions about my database or other classes or anything. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: put after execute `printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($statement)); exit;` to see if you have an error related to statement and post it if present. Or store it into `$response` and pass back to your app that calls php. for example this way `$response = mysqli_stmt_error($statement);` Once you know what exactly problem is you're on the way to solve it. You can also get an array of last errors [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error-list.php). Probably your php does not return false but `$response["success"] = false;` and while loop is not executed

Comment: Dont use the `@` error supressor

Comment: There is a [documented way](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) to check the connection was made. Please use it

Comment: You are a JAVA programmer, why dont you use the OO Mysql syntax, its so much easier to read and understand

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: I tried ("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($statement)); exit; .. it return error.

Comment: I tried the init_set too and it make no idfference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem.. it was a logic error in my php, binding ($statement, "is", $idquestion, $question) instead of ($statement, "is", $idquestion, $category) .. the given variables. Still, I don't how but i have another error now.
Look at the output
{"success":true,"idquestion":"Top programming languages?","question":"computers","id":1}
it was suppose to be
{"success":true,"idquestion":1,"question":"Top programming languages?","id":1}